# Ensuring sequential execution of onClick method in one element(Element has multiple classes, each with one onclick jquery function)

Tags: html, jquery, onclick, pug

I'm working on a project, and have some problems with jquery.

`button(class="my-btn do-btn")`

Both my-btn and do-btn have an 'onClick' jQuery each, and I need both the events to occur in sequential manner when the button is clicked.

I cannot modify the format of the element consisting two classes with one onClick function each.

How can I make sure that the my-btn jquery on click function occurs before the do-button jquery function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to add two classes and two different onClick events.
You can invoke only one onClick event and in that function you can add code accordingly as you want to operate things like following:

```
button(class="my-btn do-btn")

$(my-btn/do-btn).onClick(() => {
  first fn-call;
  second fn-call;
});

//In this way first and second will call sequentially
```